# Cannot see personal team provisioning profile in VS for Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, provisioning, visual-studio-mac

I have a problem deploying Xamarin application on my iphone with VS for Mac.

I have added account to xcode, generated ios dev certificate and successfully deployed sample swift app on my iphone. Now when i want to do the same thing with vs for mac and xamarin i can't  because i cannot select my personal team from provisioning profiles in vs. What can be the case?

[image: vs]
[image: xcode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem with you, and I found the reason may be my unregistered apple programmer account.Please see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=vsmac)

and the tip.

[tip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq6W6.png)

https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.